# Как войти в гугл аккаунт на selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

Пытался войти в гугл аккаунт на прямую не получилось, зарегался на стеке но потом когда кинул get запрос на сайт гугла(который мне нужен) сайт потребовал с меня войти в аккаунт гугл как это решить?

Comment: Потому что cookie не сохранились, вот поетому сайт требует зайти в аккаунт

Answer (score 0):

Используйте session https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/
Или передайте куки в запросе.